# Keep document not moving while new DOM element are inserted above it

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have a sequence of block elements on the [page](http://wikimedia.meteor.com/) and new elements are being added at the top all the time, pushing the rest down. I would like to make it so that once a user scrolls down and is above one block element, scrolling position follows that block element so that it does not move, even if new elements are added above te.

Comment: The short answer: Each time a new element is added, get its height and subtract it from `window.scrollY`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. If you have control of inserting the elements above, then you can calculate its height, and adjust the vertical scroll to accommodate. Keep in mind that scrolling is slightly different across browsers, so you would be safer using a framework like jQuery, which handles browser incompatibilities. Conversely, if you know your clients are using only one browser, then you can use straight javascript. The same issue applies to finding the height of an element added: your javascript code may work on some browsers and not others.